# Why, if at all, you need to flush a variable, before assigning to it?

Tags: php, wordpress

In this snippet the author of *Professional WordPress Design and Development, 2nd Edition* sets a PHP variable ($wp_query) *to NULL to completely flush it clean*.

Why you need to do this before assigning to it?

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;/***here***/
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5&paged='.$paged );/***here***/
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>

<h2>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="navigation">
<div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; Previous' ); ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link( 'More &raquo;' ); ?></div>
</div>
<?php
$wp_query = null;/***here***/
$wp_query = $temp;/***here***/
?>
```

Comment: I do not know the details from the book/code but you usually only *unset* a variable (except array entries, etc.!) to free memory. But this is only in *very* rare cases needed.

Comment: The author might be following more of a standard programming style of his own vs there being any meaningful reason in PHP to do it.

Comment: You don't. The second assignment makes the first completely redundant.

Comment: @ComFreek So in PHP if $v=1 and then you assign 2 to $v, 1 is still in memory?

Comment: that is a bad practice, you completely do not need variable swapping, why not rename $wp_query = new WP_Query() to a different name?

Comment: @user2053727 "Paging is currently designed to work only with the $wp_queryglobal variable; that is, it works within 
the default Loop and requires some sleight of hand to make it work in custom Loops. You need to 
trick WordPress into thinking your custom query is actually $wp_queryin order for paging to work." from the Professional WordPress Design and Development, 2nd Edition

Comment: @csstd i do not read the book, but the $wp_query = new WP_Query() i can make it become $abc = new WP_Query(), it's just a object creation, it had nothing to do with global variable. what the author do is save it temporary to $temp, and then use $wp_query name again to do query is useless

Comment: @csstd No, freeing memory is only meaningful for **very big** data structures (arrays). You give the GC a hint to free it with assigning *null* to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to do that. It is common practice to avoid testing against it before initialization ( something like `if($var)` before `$var` gets a value ).

Apart from keeping memory consumption low, there's no real need for `unset`ing variables. So if you have a lengthy process, you might use less peak memory if you unset intermediate variables.

As an example for freeing memory consider the following example :

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
print memory_get_usage().'/'.memory_get_usage(true).'<br />';
$a = 1;
print memory_get_usage().'/'.memory_get_usage(true).'<br />';
```

Running on one of my servers, the output is this :

```
622808/786432
621216/786432
```

The first figure is the memory you have allocated to your script, the second is what PHP is allocated from the OS (to my understanding -- please correct me if wrong). The figures are in bytes.

So you can see the memory effectively gets freed to PHP, but not the system. Once the thread terminates, the thread memory is released back to the OS. Do note that using `memory_get_usage(true)` actually calls the garbage collector, which can lower your peak consumption in intensive scripts.

Comment: So in PHP if $v=1 and then you assign 2 to $v, 1 is still in memory?

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon to initialize variables at the top of the program, which your example does, albeit somewhat unnecessarily.

Initializing variables is done so that people who read the code can see what variables will be used further down in the code. If you only initialize variables when you need them then it can make the code more difficult to understand at a glance.

As for good/bad practice, it does not really come into play here. It is a style of coding that has its time and place. It is particularly useful when writing proper algorithms, where you need to keep your tongue straight in your mouth, but when writing code that does easy stuff it is not always necessary.

As for the last two lines, they do not seem to do anything (unless this is just a part of the code). The variable is just set to `null` and then set to `$temp`, and that is it. If that really is the end of the code then you can just remove it, if you want.